# Two identical alert views shown in sequence. How can I differentiate between texts from alert 1 and alert 2?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

In my app I display a first alert view asking for password and userid followed by:

```
 NSString username1 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
 NSString password1 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text;
```

Next I display the exact alert view for a second time but this time, empty and with a different message just to confirm the password and userid before creating credentials. It is followed by:

```
 NSString username2 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
 NSString password2 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text;
```

But looks like username2 and password2 pick up values from username1 and password1. In fact if I type a different value in username2 for example, it is reflected in username1!

I read somewhere I should use something called 'tag'. So how do I tie this 'tag' thing with credentials1 as opposed to credentials2 so that I get independent values from alert1 and alert2? In order to compare these values and make sure user inputs correct credentials.

Or, is there some other simple(r) way?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `UITextField`s being used are the same, then the `NSString` pointer returned by the `text` property will always reflect whatever is in the field regardless of the contents at the time you access the property. You need to `copy` the string:

```
NSString username1 = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text copy];
NSString password1 = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text copy];
```

if you are not using ARC then of course you must also release these when done:

```
[username1 release];
[password1 release];
```